# TSQL calculate the number of records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, count

I have 3 tables with relationships sets between them. Everything works fine.

**Table Producent:**

```
ProducentID (PK, int)
ProducentName (nvarchar)
```

**Table Produced:**

```
ProducentID (PK, FK, int)
FilmID (PK, FK, int)
```

**Table Film:**

```
FilmID (PK, int)
FilmName (nvarchar)
```

Each producent produced various number of films.

**I need to generate the following output:**

```
ProducentName | NumberOfProducedFilms
```

For example:

```
ProducentName | NumberOfProducedFilms
-------------------------------------
Peter P.      | 2
John J.       | 4
Michael M.    | 7
Edward E.     | 3
```

Comment: provide more details about your tables and their relations and your desired result

Comment: What have you tried? Why didn't it work? What didn't you understand about the tutorials/documentation that you read?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `count` and `group by` as follows

```
SELECT P.producentname,
       Count(filmName) NumberOfProducedFilms
FROM   producent P
       JOIN produced PD
         ON P.producentid = PD.producentid
       JOIN film F
         ON PD.filmid = F.filmid
GROUP  BY P.producentname
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @RF1991 for the hint!

This is the full answer:

```
SELECT P.ProducentName, COUNT(PD.FilmID) NumberOfProducedFilms FROM Producent P
JOIN Produced PD ON P.ProducentID = PD.ProducentID
JOIN Film F ON PD.FilmID = F.FilmID
GROUP BY P.ProducentName
ORDER BY P.ProducentName ASC
```

Comment: Why did you copy RF1991's code and pasted it as your answer? Take some time to read this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251399/10498828